# C++ Airfare Charge Calculation project

Tags: c++

I have to create a program to calculate charges for airfare. It's a simple program so far and I am not done adding to it, but every time I run it the result turns out to be 0. Is there something missing in my code? I am a beginner and I would appreciate any advice on improving my code. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
            using namespace std;

            void main () {

                int distance = 0;
                int num_bags= 0;
                int num_meals= 0;
                double distance_price = distance * 0.15;
                double bag_price = num_bags * 25.00;
                double meal_price = num_meals * 10.00;
                double total_airfare = 0.00;


            cout << "CorsairAir Fare Calculator" << endl;

            cout << "Enter the distance being travelled:  " << endl;
            cin >> distance;

            cout << "Enter number of bags checked:  " <<endl;
            cin >> num_bags;


            cout << "Enter the number of meals ordered:  " << endl;
            cin >> num_meals;


            total_airfare = (distance_price + bag_price + meal_price);


            cout << total_airfare;




            }
```

Comment: You seem to believe that, once you wrote `double distance_price = distance * 0.15;`, now every time `distance` changes `distance_price` would magically recalculate itself. This is not the case.

Comment: Technically your program is ill-formed, `main` is specified in the C++ specification to always return an `int`.

Comment: How I wish calculating airfares was this easy... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is completely understandable - the piece you're missing is that when you assign a variable, you're assigning the left side to the result of the right side *at that moment in time*. It's not like algebra, where you say `f(x) = x + 5` and `f(x)` is always whatever `x + 5` is.

So, you assign `double distance_price = distance * 0.15` when `distance` is `0` (which you just initialized). `distance_price` remains `0` even after you ask for input and change `distance`.

Do your price calculations after you ask for input, and everything will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the `distance_price` `bag_price` `meal_price` with default values i.e. `0` not with the value which you took from user.

Below code works fine and you won't see the issue.

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    // My compiler did not allow void main so used int main
    int main () {

    int distance = 0;
    int num_bags= 0;
    int num_meals= 0;

    double distance_price ;
    double bag_price ;
    double meal_price;
    double total_airfare;

    cout << "CorsairAir Fare Calculator" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the distance being travelled:  " << endl;
    cin >> distance;

    cout << "Enter number of bags checked:  " <<endl;
    cin >> num_bags;


    cout << "Enter the number of meals ordered:  " << endl;
    cin >> num_meals;


    distance_price = distance * 0.15;
    bag_price = num_bags * 25.00;
    meal_price = num_meals * 10.00;
    total_airfare = 0.00;


    total_airfare = distance_price + bag_price + meal_price;


    cout << total_airfare;
    return 0;
    }
```

**Result**

```
CorsairAir Fare Calculator
Enter the distance being travelled:
200
Enter number of bags checked:
2
Enter the number of meals ordered:
2
100
```